# Keyboard shortcut in console, input - output

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, input, c++17

I'm learning programming from Stroustrup's book "The programming. Principles and practice using C++"
There was a problem with the file not being executed in Visual Studio 22 (checking for duplicate words)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string previous = " "; 
    std::string current; 
    while (std::cin>>current){ 
        if (previous == current)
            std::cout << "Repititive word: " << current << '\n';
    }
}
```

When entering a sentence, for example "the cat cat jumped" I press Ctrl+Z and Enter and the program does not execute.
I read that cmd.exe sends text line by line, but I can’t figure out how to enter one word at a time.
Where in the code is it correct to enter the end-of-file character?
And what modern literature would you recommend?

I tried placing the symbol EOF after cin>>current :  while (cin>>current EOF)
If I did not enter words on the console, but simply typed Ctrl+Z and Enter, then the computer reports that the program was completed successfully.
Thanks

Comment: Tactical note: [Make use of the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022) to step through the program and observe the variables being used or semi-regularly print out the variables you're using to make sure they contain the values you expect them to. When debugging you should always be looking for the earliest place where the program does something unexpected, and that means sometimes you need more diagnostic information.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows' console, to feed an `EOF` to the input stream, you need to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> **on a blank line**.

However, the problem you have in your code is that your are not assigning the 'just processed' `current` string to `previous`; thus, the test `previous == current` will always be false, as `previous` is a blank string and the `cin <<` operator doesn't read whitespace for string input.

Add a `previous = current` assignment at the end of your `while` loop and the program will work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string previous = " ";
    std::string current;
    while (std::cin >> current) {
        if (previous == current) {
            std::cout << "Repititive word: " << current << '\n';
        }
        previous = current; // Add this: Assign last "current" to "previous"
    }
}
```

You can type "the cat cat jumped`<Enter>`" all on one line, or one word per line; either way, the repetition of "cat" will be detected. When you're done, just type `^Z<Enter>` on a new line.